# Filtering Ember results

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can work with Ember.js(rc0) and Rails, and have a simple app working as I'd expect, but want to focus on a specific story:

As a user, I want to type in "filter" text in a form, then have my ArrayController only show me those items that match the filter.  For example, think of a Contacts app that shows people with the name like "Ya%"...

Caveat: Say the database holds thousands of Contact records.  I don't want to filter those contacts on the client, it makes more sense to do that on the server.

Question:
How do I do this in ember.js/ember-data?  On the server, I can easily allow for a search parameter in my index URL to filter data so it's a manageable list, or even limit the response to say, 20 items.

I can also use a view to have access to my filter text in my controller, but where do I go next? How can I pass that filter onto the server?

Update:

I was able to use "find" on the model object, and ember (ember data) went to the server to grab new data - as the client side only had a subset of all the Contact records to begin with.  Instead of filtering on what on the client, it automatically deferred to the the server...  which is nice.

```
App.ContactIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
 search_term: null
 submit: (view) ->
   this.set('content', App.Contact.find({search: "#{view.search_term}"}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for `findQuery`. For example:

```
store.findQuery(App.Contact, {q: queryString})
```

This will in turn call `findQuery` on the appropriate adapter, and if successful, load the returned records into the store and return a `DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`.

Note that you can completely customize the query object to include params that match your server's endpoints.

---

*Update*: As Michael pointed out in the comments, the above is equivalent to:

```
App.Contact.find({q: queryString})
```

... which is certainly a cleaner solution, especially without direct access to the store.

Comment: Hmm - How do I get a handle on that store object?  For example, I'll want to access that information in a controller after a user defines a text filter...

Comment: Might that api (findQuery) be gone in the RC?  I was able to use "find" on the controller, and that went back to the server database: this.set('content', App.Contact.find({search: "#{view.search_term}"})), where I support a search param in my server controller...

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGrassotti - that is the more conventional way to call findQuery now. I just updated my answer.